# how to sort query result in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sort query result into an array.

I have following query.

```
"select s.*, a.* from students left join addresses as a";
```

it returns

```
s.id
s.name
a.id
a.student_id
a.address
```

I would like to make above result into an array with s and a keys.

```
array(
  "s"=>array("id"=>"value","name"=>"value")
  ,"a"=>array("id"=>"value","student_id"=>"value","address"=>"value)
)
```

do I have to make my own function to do it or is there an internal function?

Comment: Paolo Bergantino // thanks!. I was about to modify my question :)

Comment: No problem; as far as the question, why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: I agree with Paolo - why do you need this?

Comment: I am trying to make model relationship that of cakephp on my own. I need to make left join query that involes more than 2 tables. so...I have to sort each table's fields into array as I asked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: *In your current code I believe s.id will get overwritten by a.id if you select rows as associative arrays.*

Now, on to one possible approach...

One aspect of how the results are returned is you lose the table from which the column came. If you find yourself wanting to do post-processing on the resultset, perhaps you could alias each column by renaming it like so:

```
$query = "SELECT
    s.id         AS s_id
    s.name       AS s_name
    a.id         AS a_id
    a.student_id AS a_student_id
    a.address    AS a_address
    ... ";
```

Once you have that you can organize the data based on substr($key,0,1) and get the "underlying column name with substr($key,2).

Once you have those you can loop inside each row to create the data structure you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it yourself if for no other reason than the table isn't identifiable in PHP from the query result. You only get the column name.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true - depending on what library he's using to query this data. mysqli, for example, let's you get this info http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php